# R: Iterate a vector by dropping and adding variables for a loop

Tags: r, vector

Consider a vector:

`dim <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")`

I want to be able to create versions of the vector by dropping some variables and then using the updated vector for my loop.

For eg:

I want it to iterate to all possible vectors that can results from this:

```
    dim <- c("a", "b", "d")
```

So on and so forth. Could I do this in a loop or someway that I do not have to specify anything. Order doesn't matter, so I do not want a,b,c and c,a,b

Comment: Are you looking for all permutations of `c("a", "b", "c", "d")`?

Comment: Yes! I believe so

Comment: I think maybe you mean all subsets: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18715580 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972725 ?

Comment: Yes, I do mean all subsets. But these questions create the power sets and not subsets

Comment: The power set is the set of all subsets, though, right? If you only want strict subsets, James answer from the second link can be adapted like `lapply(1:(length(dim)-1), function(x) combn(dim, x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this with:

```
dim <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
> Map(combn, list(dim), 1:length(dim))

[[1]]  # All combinations of size 1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d" 

[[2]]  # All combinations of size 2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "c"  "d"  "d" 

[[3]]  # All combinations of size 3
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b" 
[2,] "b"  "b"  "c"  "c" 
[3,] "c"  "d"  "d"  "d" 

[[4]]  # All combinations of size 4
     [,1]
[1,] "a" 
[2,] "b" 
[3,] "c" 
[4,] "d"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for all combinations of `dim` you can check out the function `combn` from the `combinat` package:

```
combinat::combn(letters[1:4], 1, simplify = F)

    [[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[3]]
[1] "c"

[[4]]
[1] "d"

combinat::combn(letters[1:4], 2, simplify = F)
combinat::combn(letters[1:4], 3, simplify = F)
combinat::combn(letters[1:4], 4, simplify = F)
```

Comment: I do not care about the order, I do not want repetition of the same 4 elements. I want like ```[[1]] [1] "a" "b"     [[2]][1]"a" "b" "c" .....  ```

Comment: Ok i see, you are looking for combinations then :). I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

In base `R` I would use either of the `for`-loop, `sapply` or `lapply`

**`for`-loop**

```
for (i in seq_along(dim)) {
  print(dim[-i])
}

[1] "b" "c" "d"
[1] "a" "c" "d"
[1] "a" "b" "d"
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

**`sapply`**

```
t( sapply(seq_along(dim), function(i) dim[-i]) )

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "b"  "c"  "d" 
[2,] "a"  "c"  "d" 
[3,] "a"  "b"  "d" 
[4,] "a"  "b"  "c"
```

**`lapply`**

```
lapply(seq_along(dim), function(i) dim[-i])

[[1]]
[1] "b" "c" "d"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "c" "d"

[[3]]
[1] "a" "b" "d"

[[4]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```